# ffmpeg 2 pass encoding on aws Lamba

Tags: ffmpeg, aws-lambda

I'm doing a 2 pass encoding with ffmpeg on AWS Lambda. Ffmpeg needs to create a temporary log file on first pass, that is used on the second pass.

Since Lambda allows write operations only in "/tmp/", I get the following expected error:

```
Cannot write log file 'ffmpeg2pass-0.log' for pass-1 encoding: Read-only file system
```

How can I force ffmpeg to write the log file in a specific directory ? -passlogfile doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: Share full command and log when you try with passlogfile

Answer (score -1):

My wrong. -passlogfile does work. And it also has to be specified in the second pass call.